# I was working on a movie sentiment analysis but, code but i'm facing issues in my code related to processing words

Tags: nlp, nltk, sentiment-analysis

My data set has 42,000 rows. This is the code I used to edit my text before vectorizing it. However the problem is it has a nested for loop which I guess makes it very slow and I'm not being able to use it with more than 1500 rows. Can someone please help out on a better way to do this?

```
filtered = []
for i in range(2):
    rev = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]', ' ', df['text'][i])
    rev = rev.lower()
    rev = rev.split()
    filtered =[]
    for word in rev:
        if word not in stopwords.words("english"):
            word = PorterStemmer().stem(word)
            filtered.append(word)
    filtered = " ".join(filtered)
    corpus.append(filtered)
```

Comment: Plese read the description of the [tag:ml] tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used [line_profiler](https://github.com/pyutils/line_profiler) to measure the speed of the code you posted.

The measurement results are as follows.

```
Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
     8                                           @profile
     9                                           def profile_nltk():
    10         1     435819.0 435819.0      0.3      df = pd.read_csv('IMDB_Dataset.csv')  # (50000, 2)
    11         1          1.0      1.0      0.0      filtered = []
    12         1        247.0    247.0      0.0      reviews = df['review'][:4000]
    13         1          0.0      0.0      0.0      corpus = []
    14      4001     216341.0     54.1      0.1      for i in range(len(reviews)):
    15      4000     221885.0     55.5      0.2          rev = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]', ' ', df['review'][i])
    16      4000       3878.0      1.0      0.0          rev = rev.lower()
    17      4000      30209.0      7.6      0.0          rev = rev.split()
    18      4000       1097.0      0.3      0.0          filtered = []
    19    950808     235589.0      0.2      0.2          for word in rev:
    20    946808  115658060.0    122.2     78.2              if word not in stopwords.words("english"):
    21    486614   30898223.0     63.5     20.9                  word = PorterStemmer().stem(word)
    22    486614     149604.0      0.3      0.1                  filtered.append(word)
    23      4000      11290.0      2.8      0.0          filtered = " ".join(filtered)
    24      4000       1429.0      0.4      0.0          corpus.append(filtered)
```

As @parsa-abbasi pointed out, the process of checking the stopword accounts for about 80% of the total.

The measurement results for the modified script are as follows. The same process has been reduced to about 1/100th of the processing time.

```
Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
     8                                           @profile
     9                                           def profile_nltk():
    10         1     441467.0 441467.0      1.4      df = pd.read_csv('IMDB_Dataset.csv')  # (50000, 2)
    11         1          1.0      1.0      0.0      filtered = []
    12         1        335.0    335.0      0.0      reviews = df['review'][:4000]
    13         1          1.0      1.0      0.0      corpus = []
    14         1       2696.0   2696.0      0.0      stopwords_set = stopwords.words('english')
    15      4001      59013.0     14.7      0.2      for i in range(len(reviews)):
    16      4000     186393.0     46.6      0.6          rev = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]', ' ', df['review'][i])
    17      4000       3657.0      0.9      0.0          rev = rev.lower()
    18      4000      27357.0      6.8      0.1          rev = rev.split()
    19      4000        999.0      0.2      0.0          filtered = []
    20    950808     220673.0      0.2      0.7          for word in rev:
    21                                                       # if word not in stopwords.words("english"):
    22    946808    1201271.0      1.3      3.8              if word not in stopwords_set:
    23    486614   29479712.0     60.6     92.8                  word = PorterStemmer().stem(word)
    24    486614     141242.0      0.3      0.4                  filtered.append(word)
    25      4000      10412.0      2.6      0.0          filtered = " ".join(filtered)
    26      4000       1329.0      0.3      0.0          corpus.append(filtered)
```

I hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The most time-consuming part of the written code is the stopwords part.
It will call the library to get the list of stopwords each time the loop iterates.
Therefore it's better to get the stopwords set once and use the same set at each iteration.
I rewrote the code as following (other differences are made just for the sake of the readability):

```
corpus = []
texts = df['text']
stopwords_set = stopwords.words("english")
stemmer = PorterStemmer()
for i in range(len(texts)):
    rev = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]', ' ', texts[i])
    rev = rev.lower()
    rev = rev.split()
    filtered = []
    filtered = [stemmer.stem(word) for word in rev if word not in stopwords_set]
    filtered = " ".join(filtered)
    corpus.append(filtered)
```